# Regular expression matching a multiline block of text

Tags: python, regex, multiline

I'm having a bit of trouble getting a Python regex to work when matching against text that spans multiple lines. The example text is (`\n` is a newline)

```plaintext
some Varying TEXT\n
\n
DSJFKDAFJKDAFJDSAKFJADSFLKDLAFKDSAF\n
[more of the above, ending with a newline]\n
[yep, there is a variable number of lines here]\n
\n
(repeat the above a few hundred times).
```

I'd like to capture two things:

- the `some Varying TEXT` part
- all lines of uppercase text that come two lines below it in one
  capture (I can strip out the newline characters later).

I've tried a few approaches:

```python
re.compile(r"^>(\w+)$$([.$]+)^$", re.MULTILINE) # try to capture both parts
re.compile(r"(^[^>][\w\s]+)$", re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL) # just textlines
```

...and a lot of variations hereof with no luck. The last one seems to match the lines of text one by one, which is not what I really want. I can catch the first part, no problem, but I can't seem to catch the 4-5 lines of uppercase text.
I'd like `match.group(1)` to be `some Varying Text` and `group(2)` to be line1+line2+line3+etc until the empty line is encountered.

If anyone's curious, it's supposed to be a sequence of amino acids that make up a protein.

Comment: Is there something else in the file besides the first line and the uppercase text? I'm not sure why you would use a regex instead of splitting all the text at newline characters and taking the first element as "some_Varying_TEXT".

Comment: yes, regex are the wrong tool for this.

Comment: Your sample text doesn't have a leading `>` character.  Should it?

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Try this:

```
re.compile(r"^(.+)\n((?:\n.+)+)", re.MULTILINE)
```

I think your biggest problem is that you're expecting the `^` and `$` anchors to match linefeeds, but they don't.  In multiline mode, `^` matches the position immediately *following* a newline and `$` matches the position immediately *preceding* a newline.

Be aware, too, that a newline can consist of a linefeed (`\n`), a carriage-return (`\r`), or a carriage-return+linefeed (`\r\n`).  If you aren't certain that your target text uses only linefeeds, you should use this more inclusive version of the regex:

```
re.compile(r"^(.+)(?:\n|\r\n?)((?:(?:\n|\r\n?).+)+)", re.MULTILINE)
```

BTW, you don't want to use the DOTALL modifier here; you're relying on the fact that the dot matches everything *except* newlines.

Comment: You may want to replace the second dot in the regex by [A-Z] if you don't want this regular expression to match just about any text file with an empty second line.  ;-)

Comment: My impression is that the target files will conform to a definite (and repeating) pattern of empty vs. non-empty lines, so it shouldn't be necessary to specify [A-Z], but it probably won't hurt, either.

Comment: This solution worked beautifully. As an aside, I apologize, since I obviously didn't clarify the situation enough (and also for the lateness of this reply). Thanks for your help!

Comment: At least newer [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) says that platform-specific line endings are abstracted away to `\n` both when reading and writing. So you can pretend that non-Unix platforms don't exist .

Answer (score 31):

This will work:

```
>>> import re
>>> rx_sequence=re.compile(r"^(.+?)\n\n((?:[A-Z]+\n)+)",re.MULTILINE)
>>> rx_blanks=re.compile(r"\W+") # to remove blanks and newlines
>>> text="""Some varying text1
...
... AAABBBBBBCCCCCCDDDDDDD
... EEEEEEEFFFFFFFFGGGGGGG
... HHHHHHIIIIIJJJJJJJKKKK
...
... Some varying text 2
...
... LLLLLMMMMMMNNNNNNNOOOO
... PPPPPPPQQQQQQRRRRRRSSS
... TTTTTUUUUUVVVVVVWWWWWW
... """
>>> for match in rx_sequence.finditer(text):
...   title, sequence = match.groups()
...   title = title.strip()
...   sequence = rx_blanks.sub("",sequence)
...   print "Title:",title
...   print "Sequence:",sequence
...   print
...
Title: Some varying text1
Sequence: AAABBBBBBCCCCCCDDDDDDDEEEEEEEFFFFFFFFGGGGGGGHHHHHHIIIIIJJJJJJJKKKK

Title: Some varying text 2
Sequence: LLLLLMMMMMMNNNNNNNOOOOPPPPPPPQQQQQQRRRRRRSSSTTTTTUUUUUVVVVVVWWWWWW
```

---

Some explanation about this regular expression might be useful: `^(.+?)\n\n((?:[A-Z]+\n)+)`

- The first character (`^`) means "starting at the beginning of a line".  Be aware that it does not match the newline itself (same for $: it means "just before a newline", but it does not match the newline itself).
- Then `(.+?)\n\n` means "match as few characters as possible (all characters are allowed) until you reach two newlines".  The result (without the newlines) is put in the first group.
- `[A-Z]+\n` means "match as many upper case letters as possible until you reach a newline.  This defines what I will call a *textline*.
- `((?:`*textline*`)+)` means match one or more *textlines* but do not put each line in a group. Instead, put **all** the *textlines* in one group.
- You could add a final `\n` in the regular expression if you want to enforce a double newline at the end.
- Also, if you are not sure about what type of newline you will get (`\n` or `\r` or `\r\n`) then just fix the regular expression by replacing every occurrence of `\n` by `(?:\n|\r\n?)`.

Comment: match() only returns one match, at the very beginning of the target text, but the OP said there would be hundreds of matches per file.  I think you would want finditer() instead.

Answer (score 26):

The following is a regular expression matching a multiline block of text:

```
import re
result = re.findall('(startText)(.+)((?:\n.+)+)(endText)',input)
```

Comment: this is a great answer- you may have to modify if you need to span multiple linebreaks in a row `\n\n`

Answer (score 5):

If each file only has one sequence of aminoacids, I wouldn't use regular expressions at all.  Just something like this:

```
def read_amino_acid_sequence(path):
    with open(path) as sequence_file:
        title = sequence_file.readline() # read 1st line
        aminoacid_sequence = sequence_file.read() # read the rest

    # some cleanup, if necessary
    title = title.strip() # remove trailing white spaces and newline
    aminoacid_sequence = aminoacid_sequence.replace(" ","").replace("\n","")
    return title, aminoacid_sequence
```

Comment: Definitively the easiest way if there was only one, and its also workable with more, if some more logic is added. There's about 885 proteins in this specific dataset though, and I felt that a regex should be able to handle this.

Answer (score 4):

find:

```
^>([^\n\r]+)[\n\r]([A-Z\n\r]+)
```

\1 = some_varying_text

\2 = lines of all CAPS

**Edit (proof that this works):**

```
text = """> some_Varying_TEXT

DSJFKDAFJKDAFJDSAKFJADSFLKDLAFKDSAF
GATACAACATAGGATACA
GGGGGAAAAAAAATTTTTTTTT
CCCCAAAA

> some_Varying_TEXT2

DJASDFHKJFHKSDHF
HHASGDFTERYTERE
GAGAGAGAGAG
PPPPPAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP
"""

import re

regex = re.compile(r'^>([^\n\r]+)[\n\r]([A-Z\n\r]+)', re.MULTILINE)
matches = [m.groups() for m in regex.finditer(text)]
#NOTE can be sorter with matches = re.findall(pattern, text, re.MULTILINE)

for m in matches:
    print 'Name: %s\nSequence:%s' % (m[0], m[1])
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this regular expression will also match groups of capital letters separated by empty lines.  It might not be a big deal though.

Comment: Looks like coonj likes FASTA files. ;)

Answer (score 4):

It can sometimes be comfortable to specify the flag directly inside the string, as an [inline-flag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
"(?m)^A complete line$".
```

For example in unit tests, with [assertRaisesRegex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaisesRegex). That way, you don't need to `import re`, or compile your regex before calling the assert.

Answer (score 1):

My preference.

```
lineIter= iter(aFile)
for line in lineIter:
    if line.startswith( ">" ):
         someVaryingText= line
         break
assert len( lineIter.next().strip() ) == 0
acids= []
for line in lineIter:
    if len(line.strip()) == 0:
        break
    acids.append( line )
```

At this point you have someVaryingText as a string, and the acids as a list of strings.
You can do `"".join( acids )` to make a single string.

I find this less frustrating (and more flexible) than multiline regexes.