# Identify Sentences in Text

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string

I am having a bit of a trouble correctly identifying sentences in a text for specific corner cases:

1. If a dot, dot, dot is involved, this will not be kept.
2. If `"` are involved.
3. If a sentence accidentally start with a lower case.

This is how I identify sentences in text so far (source: [Subtitles Reformat to end with complete sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56124718/subtitles-reformat-to-end-with-complete-sentence/56125308#56125308)):

`re.findall` part basically looks for a chunk of `str` that starts with a capital letter, `[A-Z]`, then anything except the punctuation, then ends with the punctuation, `[\.?!]`.

```
import re
text = "We were able to respond to the first research question. Next, we also determined the size of the population."
    for sentence in re.findall(r'([A-Z][^\.!?]*[\.!?])', text):
        print(sentence + "\n")
```

> ```
> We were able to respond to the first research question.
>
> Next, we also determined the size of the population.
> ```

Corner Case 1: **Dot, Dot, Dot**

The dot,dot,dot, is not kept, since there are no instructions given for what to do if three dots appear in a row. How could this be changed ?

```
text = "We were able to respond to the first research question... Next, we also determined the size of the population."
for sentence in re.findall(r'([A-Z][^\.!?]*[\.!?])', text):
    print(sentence + "\n")
```

> ```
> We were able to respond to the first research question.
>
> Next, we also determined the size of the population.
> ```

Corner Case 2: **"**

The `"`symbol is successfully kept within a sentence, but like the dot's following the punctuation, it will be deleted at the end.

```
text = "We were able to respond to the first \"research\" question: \"What is this?\" Next, we also determined the size of the population."
for sentence in re.findall(r'([A-Z][^\.!?]*[\.!?])', text):
    print(sentence + "\n")
```

> ```
> We were able to respond to the first "research" question: "What is this?
>
> Next, we also determined the size of the population.
> ```

Corner Case 3: **lower case start of a sentence**

If a sentence accidentally starts with a lower case, the sentence will be ignored. The aim would be to identify that a previous sentence ended (or the text just started) and hence a new sentence has to start.

```
text = "We were able to respond to the first research question. next, we also determined the size of the population."
for sentence in re.findall(r'([A-Z][^\.!?]*[\.!?])', text):
    print(sentence + "\n")
```

> `We were able to respond to the first research question.`

### Edit

I tested it:

```
import spacy
from spacy.lang.en import English

raw_text = 'Hello, world. Here are two sentences.'
nlp = English()
doc = nlp(raw_text)
sentences = [sent.string.strip() for sent in doc.sents]
```

...but I get:

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-157-4fd093d3402b> in <module>()
>       6 nlp = English()
>       7 doc = nlp(raw_text)
> ----> 8 sentences = [sent.string.strip() for sent in doc.sents]
>
> <ipython-input-157-4fd093d3402b> in <listcomp>(.0)
>       6 nlp = English()
>       7 doc = nlp(raw_text)
> ----> 8 sentences = [sent.string.strip() for sent in doc.sents]
>
> doc.pyx in sents()
>
> ValueError: [E030] Sentence boundaries unset. You can add the 'sentencizer' component to the pipeline with:
> nlp.add_pipe(nlp.create_pipe('sentencizer')) Alternatively, add the
> dependency parser, or set sentence boundaries by setting
> doc[i].is_sent_start.
> ```

Comment: Good idea. Might do that, if not other options are available.

Comment: Not about your corner cases, but a general thought: Maybe you can just split your text into sentences using the indicator `. ` , a single dot followed by space, not preceded by other dots? If at least this would be a common factor, all other thinks like quotation marks etc. could be ignored, but i'm just guessing around. To create a regex matching a dot not preceded by other specified characters, see: https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could modify your regex to match your corner cases.

First of all, you do not need to escape `.` inside `[]`

For the first corner case, you can greedily match the ending-sentance-token with `[.!?]*`

For the second, you can potentially match `"` after `[.!?]`

For the last one, you can start your sentance with either upper or lower :

```
import re

regex = r'([A-z][^.!?]*[.!?]*"?)'

text = "We were able to respond to the first research question... Next, we also determined the size of the population."
for sentence in re.findall(regex, text):
    print(sentence)
print()

text = "We were able to respond to the first \"research\" question: \"What is this?\" Next, we also determined the size of the population."
for sentence in re.findall(regex, text):
    print(sentence)
print()

text = "We were able to respond to the first research question. next, we also determined the size of the population."
for sentence in re.findall(regex, text):
    print(sentence)
```

### Explanation

- `[A-z]`, every match should start with a letter, either upper or lower.
- `[^.?!]*`, it matches greedily any character which is not `.`, `?` or `!` (an ending sentance character)
- `[.?!]*`, it matches greedily the ending characters, so `...??!!???` will be match as part of the sentance
- `"?`, it eventually matches a quote at the end of the sentance

Corner case 1:

> We were able to respond to the first research question...
>   Next, we also determined the size of the population.

Corner case 2:

> We were able to respond to the first "research" question: "What is this?"
>   Next, we also determined the size of the population.

Corner case 3:

> We were able to respond to the first research question.
>   next, we also determined the size of the population.

Comment: Great answer !! This is what I was looking for. Just a quick question: What do you mean by " it matches greedily" ?

Comment: It means that `...` will be matched, a non greedy matching with `*?` will not match `...`

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use some of the industrial packages for that. For example, [spacy](https://spacy.io/) has a very good sentence tokenizer.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals, print_function
from spacy.en import English

raw_text = 'Hello, world. Here are two sentences.'
nlp = English()
doc = nlp(raw_text)
sentences = [sent.string.strip() for sent in doc.sents]
```

Your scenarios:

1. case result -> `['We were able to respond to the first research question...', 'Next, we also determined the size of the population.']`
2. case result -> `['We were able to respond to the first "research" question: "What is this?"', 'Next, we also determined the size of the population.']`
3. case result -> `['We were able to respond to the first research question.', 'next, we also determined the size of the population.']`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is this free ?

Comment: Yes, it is. No problem :)

Comment: Would you mind trying the three examples of my question and posting the results in your answer ?

Comment: Would you mind having a look at my updated question ? I tested your method, but I keep getting an error.

Comment: I haven't seen that error. Try going to the Spacy page and try to download everything that you need (like neg dictionary etc.). That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:
([A-Z][^.!?]*[.!?]+["]?)

'+' means one or more

'?' means zero or more

This should pass all 3 corner cases you mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

Responding to the Edited question:

I think the code you are using is for an older version of spacy. For Spacy3.0 you need to download the *en_core_web_sm* model first:

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

then the following solution should work:

```
raw_text = 'Hello, world. Here are two sentences.'
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp(raw_text)
sentences = [sent for sent in doc.sents]
print(sentences)
```

Output -

> [Hello, world., Here are two sentences.]