# Regular expression to replace lines in a text which starts with a specific char

Tags: python, regex

I'm working on a regular expression but I just can't make it work.

With a text like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ultricies congue feugiat. 

Tom wrote:
> blablabla
> this is very interesting 
> blabla blabla
> I ate a apple yesterday
> this is very interesting 
> blabla blabla

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ultricies congue feugiat.
```

I Would like to match the whole part of the text that starts with "Tom wrote:" and that ends with last line starting with a ">" in order to remove it and to get only the 2 lorem ipsum sentences.

I don't know if I'm clear enough...

Edit: I was thinking about a regexp that match everything that starts with "\w wrote: " and that stops when it matches a newline followed by a char that is not a ">"

Edit2: Found a solution :

```
\w+ wrote:(\n>[^\n]*)*
```

Comment: We still would like to know what you got so far first.

Comment: I tried:
(\w+ wrote:)|(>.*?\n)

But it doesn't take the last line if it doesn't end with a newline

Plus it isn't correct as it would also remove lines with starts with a ">" but which are not preceded by "xxx wrote :"

Comment: Giving your question a good title means that other people with a similar issue can find your question and (hopefully) an answer.

Comment: Why do you all rate it down....

Comment: You may have wanted this, but your posted solution will match lines that look like "Bob wrote:" even if it has no lines starting with ">" after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matching regular expressions across multiple lines requires specifying multiline matching.

See this answer for details:
[Regular expression matching a multiline block of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587345/python-regular-expression-matching-a-multiline-block-of-text)

Comment: With mutliline, matching of ^ and $ is different. Try using ^ to match line which doesn't start with >.

Answer (score 1):

Practice your regular expressions in a tool like [this one](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/).  Makes it very easy to visualize what your regex is doing.

Give this one a go and adjust as necessary:

`Tom wrote:(.|\s)*>.*`

Comment: Thank you but I already use Kodos which works perfectly fine.

Comment: What do you mean?  Matches everything after what?

Comment: It means that it will match all lines after even if they do not start with a ">"

Comment: The regex I provided is correct, you just need a global/multi-line flag as Igor suggested.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is what you want (adjust newline characters as necessary for your system)

```
\w+ wrote:\n(>.*\n)*(>.*)
```

http://regexr.com?32l21

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I found one myself that works too :)