# Read more than one line of a file

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am working on a python app to create an interface for a script(ish) visual novel framework. For now, I was able to read the file, create the *labels* or functions but when I read them, it just reads one line. Sort of like this:

```
>>> from freddie import Freddie
>>> check = Freddie()
>>> check.read_script('script')
>>> check.read_label('start')
'label start:\n' # Only reads the first line and the whitespace
```

And the entire label is:

```
label start:

    test "Lorem ipsum"

    test "Sir amet"

return
```

My function is:

```
def read_label(self, label):
    search_label = re.search("label %s(.*)\s" % label, self.scripts.read(), re.MULTILINE)
    return search_label.group()
```

Is there a way to make the regular expression read the entire label and the whitespace?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/587345/python-regular-expression-matching-a-multiline-block-of-text answers pretty much of your doubts.

Comment: Be sure to use raw strings in your regexes or character classes (like \s) won't work.

Comment: @kaotik your link did part of the job, but it reads the first line only and I want the expression to read until the return statement. Maybe there is a way to modify it a bit to make the whole thing work?

Answer (score 1):

The `.` in the regex normally matches any character *except* "\n", therefore the regex matches only the first line (the `\s` matches the "\n" at the end of that line).

If you want the `.` to match any character *including* "\n", use the `DOTALL` flag.