# Line by Line Check and Edit (Python 2.4)

Tags: python, python-2.4

I'm currently writing an anagram program in java that uses a hashmap> to store the words. The dictionary text file I have is in the format:

```
eelrss lesser
eelrssst restless
eelrsst tressel
eelrsstvy sylvester
eelrst lester
eelrstt letters
eelrstt settler
eelrstt trestle
```

The letters of each word have been put in alphabetical order next to their word and the whole file sorted in alphabetical order using the keys.What I am trying to do is format it using Python so that duplicate words are on the same line, e.g. in the above example,
eelrstt letters 
eelrstt settler

would become `eelrstt letter settler trestle`

The code I am using to try and convert this is:

```
f = open('d13.txt')
lines = f.readlines()
duped = open('checked.txt', 'w')

for i in range(len(lines)):
   line1 = lines[i].split(' ')
   line2 = lines[i+1].split(' ')
   if line1[0] != 'nm':
       if line1[0] == line2[0]:
           line3 = line1 + line2[1:]
           line2[0] = 'nm'
       else:
            line3 = line1
       line4 = ' '.join(line3)
       duped.write(line4)
```

However this produces a mess that only picks up on the next line and leaves duplicates in.

```
eelrss lesser
eelrssst restless
eelrsst tressel
eelrsstvy sylvester
eelrst lester
eelrstt letters
 settler
eelrstt settler
 trestle
eelrstt trestle
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: You have forgotten to strip `\n`. Otherwise the output is correct for the given input.

Comment: Adding strip \n gives a really weird output with multiple outputs on the same line. Do you have any suggestions for choose that would give the desired output please?

Comment: That weird output is because you have chosen to strip all of the `\n`. Change `line4 = ' '.join(line3)` to `line4 = ' '.join(line3)+'\n'`, and you will get it bettered.

Comment: I've tried doing what you suggested, but am now getting the following. `eelrrvy revelry

eelrss lesser

eelrssst restless

eelrsst tressel

eelrsstvy sylvester

eelrst lester

eelrstt letters
 settler

eelrstt settler
 trestle

eelrstt trestle

eelrstw swelter
 wrestle`

Comment: I have tried to run the modified code on [ideaone](https://ideone.com/55GdlU) and I am getting the correct output. Please look into the link.

Comment: Okay, realised I need to run it multiple times to remove duplicate entries. Thanks so much for your help and putting up with me being thick.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python regular expression matching a multiline block of text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/587345/python-regular-expression-matching-a-multiline-block-of-text)