# Python regexp everything between parenthesis on multiple lines

Tags: python, regex

My regexp is:

```
TMP_REGEXP = r'_\(\s*(.*)\s*\)\s*$'
TMP_PATTERN = re.compile(TMP_REGEXP, re.MULTILINE)
```

File input_data.txt:

```
print _(
    'Test #A'
    )              

print _(
    '''Test #B'''
    '''Test #C'''
)
```

I am running this like that:

```
with codecs.open('input_data.txt', encoding='utf-8') as flp:
    content = flp.read()

extracted = re.findall(TMP_PATTERN, content)
```

What I want to achieve is:
 - take all characters that follow '_('
 - end reading characters if there is ')' followed by zero or more whitespaces and end of line

What is interesting 'Test #A' works like a charm bu 'Test #B' is skipped.

Comment: What is there are nested parens? You'll be hosed.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/587345/python-regular-expression-matching-a-multiline-block-of-text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
m = re.findall(r'(?s)_\((.*?)\)', content)
```

`(?s)` looks for anything (including newlines).

`_\(` matches your desired start.

`(.*?)` looks for something.

`\)` matches your end.

You might want `$` at the end and to do some stripping.

```
>>> content = """
... print _(
...     'Test #A'
...     )              
... 
... print _(
...     '''Test #B'''
...     '''Test #C'''
... )
... """
>>> import re
>>> m = re.findall(r'(?s)_\((.*?)\)', content)
>>> for i, match in enumerate(m, 1):
...     print("Match {0}: {1}".format(i, match))
... 
Match 1: 
    'Test #A'

Match 2: 
    '''Test #B'''
    '''Test #C'''

>>>
```

Comment: There is one twist to figure out, what if there is Test #B ('a', 'b')\n Test #C, that is why I want to end reading when there is ) followed by nothing. But overall I am step closer, thank you.

Comment: @Drachenfels Then you can't do it with a regex. That is not a regular language, so a regex cannot match that language.

Comment: That is __not__ a lookbehind.

Comment: Personally, I would say exactly what [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.S) says:  `Make the '.' special character match any character at all, including a newline`.