# python regex find match that spans multiple lines

Tags: python, regex

So I am trying to grab the string from a BibTex using regex in python. Here is part of my string:

```
a = '''title = {The Origin ({S},
        {Se}, and {Te})- {TiO$_2$} Photocatalysts},
   year = {2010},
   volume = {114},'''
```

I want to grab the string for the title, which is:

```
The Origin ({S},
        {Se}, and {Te})- {TiO$_2$} Photocatalysts
```

I currently have this code:

```
pattern = re.compile('title\s*=\s*{(.*|\n?)},\s*\n', re.DOTALL|re.I)
pattern.findall(a)
```

But it only gives me:

```
['The Origin ({S},\n            {Se}, and {Te})- {TiO$_2$} Photocatalysts},\n       year = {2010']
```

How can I get the whole title string without the `year` information?
Many times, `year` is not right after `title`. So I cannot use:

```
pattern = re.compile('title\s*=\s*{(.*|\n?)},\s*\n.*year', re.DOTALL|re.I)
pattern.findall(a)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/587345/python-regular-expression-matching-a-multiline-block-of-text

Comment: I tried that, but still couldn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution would be to modify your regex pattern

```
pattern = re.compile('title\s*=\s*{(.*|\n?)},\s*\n', re.DOTALL|re.I)
```

Comment: I just found out this is wrong. It will grab the `year` line as well

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how general you want your regex to be. I guess you want your string to be able to contain { and }, so using that to mark the ending of the pattern will cause issues. Also there could be multiple brackets.

Here's an idea, what if you look for the word year at the end of the regex, assuming that's constant.

```
pattern = re.compile('title\s*=\s*{(.*?)},\s*\n\s*year', re.DOTALL|re.I)
```

Comment: Many times the `year` is not after `title`. But you still give me a new idea of doing this :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the newer [**`regex module`**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex):

```
import regex as re

rx = re.compile(r'''
        (?(DEFINE)
            (?<part>\w+\ =\ \{)
            (?<end>\},)
            (?<title>title\ =\ \{)
        )
        (?&title)(?P<t>(?:(?!(?&part))[\s\S])+)(?&end)
    ''', re.VERBOSE)

string = '''
title = {The Origin ({S},
        {Se}, and {Te})- {TiO$_2$} Photocatalysts},
   year = {2010},
   volume = {114},
'''

title = rx.search(string).group('t')
print(title)
# The Origin ({S},
#    {Se}, and {Te})- {TiO$_2$} Photocatalysts
```

Though it is not really needed, it provides an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

[textwrap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html) can be useful:

```
import textwrap

a = '''title = {The Origin ({S},
        {Se}, and {Te})- {TiO$_2$} Photocatalysts},
   year = {2010},
   volume = {114},'''

indent = "   "
print(textwrap.dedent(indent + a))
```