# Python3 Regex - Positive Lookahead not doing multiline

Tags: python, regex

I have some scraped content I got from `with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:` and I'm trying to run regex on it to extract some information in a `<td>...</td>`. But I can't get the regex to look further; I think the document has new lines that are getting in the way. I've tried adding `\s` or `\r` but it isn't working for me.

I'm trying to retrieve

```
The content was pretty nice and would participate again&nbsp;
```

using the regex:

```
(?<=showPollResponses\()(.*)(?=)
```

and here is a sample of the document:

```
</thead>
<tr>
<td class="oddpoll" style="width:20%"><b><a href="#" onclick="showPollResponses(123456, 99, '1A2B3C4D5E6F7G8H9I0J1K2L3M4N5O6P', 123456, 123456, 99);return false;">The stuf (i</a></b>
<br>
</td><td class="oddpoll" style="width:35%">The content was pretty nice and would participate again&nbsp;</td><td class="oddpoll" style="width:45%"><b>123 Total</b>
<br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="oddpoll">&nbsp;</td>
```

I've tried using `(?<=showPollResponses\()(.*)(?=width:45%)` but it's not returning anything. I was going to take that chunk of html and regex it further to extract the final text.

Here's my [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/4D2pCV/1)

There's not a more simple way to do this, is there? In PHP I've used tools to scrape data with css selectors, so I could easily retrieve this that way. Or in the `urllib` context, is using regex the only way? Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) for html parsing?

Comment: I'm new to Python and have never heard of it. I have a script right now that's doing Pandas parsing, but I needed to extract a quick url, and now need to extract some other text.

Comment: Have you tried setting `re.MULTILINE` flag in either `re.compile ()`or the `re.search()` function? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587345/regular-expression-matching-a-multiline-block-of-text (so this question is  probably a dupe of that).

Comment: I've set that setting in regex101 but still does not return past the new line.

Comment: It's probably an error with me. Here's what I'm doing: `with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:` then `soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")` then `print(soup.select_one("a[onclick*=showPollResponses]").find_next("td").get_text())`

Comment: In this page, there are multiple of these occurrences. Could be anywhere from 0 to a few or 5 or more. Could the existence of multiples of this selector be why it's not working? Is there a way to select them all, then access a specific one via similar to an array? [0] or [2]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing HTML with regular expressions is quite a controversial thing to do - it is only sometimes justified: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

The better way would be to utilize a specialized tool - an *HTML parser* like [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). The idea would be to locate the `a` element by a partial match on the `onclick` attribute and then get the next `td` element after the `a`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<table>
    </thead>
        <tr>
            <td class="oddpoll" style="width:20%"><b><a href="#" onclick="showPollResponses(123456, 99, '1A2B3C4D5E6F7G8H9I0J1K2L3M4N5O6P', 123456, 123456, 99);return false;">The stuf (i</a></b>
            <br>
            </td><td class="oddpoll" style="width:35%">The content was pretty nice and would participate again&nbsp;</td><td class="oddpoll" style="width:45%"><b>123 Total</b>
            <br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
    </thead>
</table>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

print(soup.select_one("a[onclick*=showPollResponses]").find_next("td").get_text())
```

Prints:

```
The content was pretty nice and would participate again
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely check into using this vs regex for getting the content I need. Real quick, the print line of code is giving the following error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next'`. Any idea why?

Comment: @Kenny sure, this is because it cannot locate the `a` element for some reason. Could you point me to the website you are downloading the source from? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't. It's internal company info, I'm just trying to manipulate it to get things I need to put together a better report.

Comment: @Kenny gotcha, no problem, are you sure you have this `a` element in the html source you are downloading?

Comment: Yes, there's definitely an anchor tag there.

Comment: @Kenny okay, do you see this tag and that `onclick` value if you would do `print(soup.find_all("a"))`?

Comment: I can retrieve it now. I was using the `response` from `urllib.request.urlopen(url)`. I guess beautiful soup only works with `import responses`? Is there a way to retrieve multiple occurrences of this into a variable that's an array?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150662/discussion-between-alecxe-and-kenny).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with `(.*)`. `.` only matches characters, so that doesn't include newlines. The way to fix this is to use `([\s\S]*)`. So without modifying your regex too much, `(?<=showPollResponses\()([\S\s]*)(?=width:45%)`.

Edit: Since your regex is matching past `(?=width:45%)`, I would make an educated guess that it occurs again later in your document. Since `([\s\S]*)` is greedy, it will match as much as it can. To remedy this, we can add `?` to match just the first iteration. So now, `(?<=showPollResponses\()([\S\s]*?)(?=width:45%)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, this works and takes it through multiple lines, but it's not stopping for me after `(?=width:45%)`. I have a larger document, and there are about 5 matches I would like it to return. I'm currently using `scrape = re.findall(r'(?<=showPollResponses\()(.*)(?=\))', response.read().decode('utf-8'))` which return an array of 5 matches.

Comment: Thank you, it's working properly at regex101.com. I'm now trying with it in my code using `question = re.findall(r'(?<=showPollResponses\()([\S\s]*?)(?=width:45%)', response.read().decode('utf-8'))` then `print(question)` but it seems to be empty. So I'll keep scrutinizing my code to figure out what may be wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem, but try removing the `r` in your findall statement. This indicates a raw strong and might not be what you need.