# How to pull lines below text that Python script has found?

Tags: python

How do you pull data several lines *below* text you are able to find? That's the short question. More context is below...

I'm learning Python and, as an exercise, I pulled baseball stats from Yahoo Fantasy Baseball to play around with. I coped and pasted the data from the webpage into a text file. It's messy and looks something like this:

```
Player Note
Charlie Blackmon Col - OF
8:40 pm vs Atl ?
?
Atl
Video Playlist
Video Forecast
Autodraft Hero
115
12
3
99%
159/474
106
27
74
11
.335
?
```

I was able to set up a simple script to pull out the line with the ballplayers name. See below.

```
a=open('batters.txt')
for line in a:
    if '-' in line:
        print(line)
```

However, I'd also like to pull home run totals (ex. 27) and batting average (ex. .335) from the data.

I'd like it to look something like this:

```
Charlie Blackmon Col - OF, HR: 27, BA: .335
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: My suggestion is that you look into Multiline regular expressions.   Regular Expressions can be daunting, but they were made for this exact use case - See this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587345/regular-expression-matching-a-multiline-block-of-text

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to use *with* statement as it's automatically closes file handler, next read all lines in file to *lines* list and access it. For example: print(lines[1]) # Charlie Blackmon Col - OF.

You can try this code snippet:

```
with open('batters.txt') as file:
   lines = file.read().splitlines()
   temp = '%s, HR: %s, BA: %s'
   result = temp % (lines[1], lines[14], lines[17], )
   print(result)
```