# Multi line string matcher with optional intervening phrase

Tags: python, regex, multiline, formatted-input

I would like to grab Text distributed between two lines.

For Example :

```
PO Number Dept.number
4000813852 7
```

I would like to get  **PO Number 4000813852**
It's like a table-based data but in the context of the whole document appears to be normal text.

I have used `re.MULTILINE` like  `r'PO Number.*\n[0-9]+'`

it workes in this case but it is not the best solution because maybe **PO Number** comes in the middle as

```
Invoice Number PO Number Dept.number
123456666     4000813852  7
```

Comment: The latter case is underspecified and a bad match for regex - you would somehow have to guess what number belongs to PO - we would need far much data to fit anything to it. You are capturing far too much text with your regex as you do not use capturing groups. Write line based/column based parser and feed it the parts  starting with the complete line that contains *PO Number* till the end of the next line

Comment: This is a near-duplicate of [Regular expression matching a multiline block of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587345/regular-expression-matching-a-multiline-block-of-text). Your only complication is adding an optional extra expression for 'Dept.number' in between 'PO Number' and \d+

Comment: Actually, unless you can apply special knowledge like "PO Numbers are 10 digits, dept numbers are 1-3" to a multiline regex, then @PatrickArtner is right. First, capture the field names from the first line. Then, figure out which fields from the second line you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with two capture groups and `re.DOTALL` option enabled. The expression assumes that the number you are interested is the only one with 10 digits in your text.

The expression is:

```
(PO\sNumber).*(\d{10})
```

Python snippet:

```
import re

first_string = """PO Number Dept.number
4000813852 7"""

second_string = """Invoice Number PO Number Dept.number
123456666     4000813853  7"""

PO_first = re.search(r'(PO\sNumber).*(\d{10})',first_string,re.DOTALL)
print(PO_first.group(1)+" "+PO_first.group(2))

PO_second = re.search(r'(PO\sNumber).*(\d{10})',second_string,re.DOTALL)
print(PO_second.group(1)+" "+PO_second.group(2))
```

Output:

```
PO Number 4000813852
PO Number 4000813853
```

Answer (score 1):

With a single regex:

```
data="""PO Number Dept.number
    4000813852 7
    Invoice Number PO Number Dept.number
    123456666     4000813852  7
    """

re.findall(r"(PO Number)\s*Dept.number\s*(?:(?:\d+)\s+(\d+)|(\d+))\s+\d",data)
Out: 
[('PO Number', '', '4000813852'), ('PO Number', '4000813852', '')]
```

I don't use re.MULTILINE, as \s matches newline,too.

Comment: It's not one string, its two different ones.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness "it's not one string," Not a problem, you can apply my regex for a single string, too.