# Howto fetch nextline with regex

Tags: python

With this code I can fetch 'John Doe' from 'Name: John Doe'.

But howto fetch when 'John Doe' is on the next line?

**Ex:**

```
Name:
John Doe

body = "Name: John Doe"
p = re.compile("Name: (.*)")
   result = p.search(str(body))
   if result:
       s = result.group(1)
```

Comment: What about this: "Name:( |\n|\r|\r\n)(.*)"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression matching a multiline block of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587345/regular-expression-matching-a-multiline-block-of-text)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure entirely what you need, but if you want to find `John Doe` *anywhere* in a given input string, then consider using `re.findall`:

```
body = "Name: John Doe\nCats don't like bats.\nBut John Doe does."
matches = re.findall(r'\bJohn Doe\b', body)
print(matches)

['John Doe', 'John Doe']
```

Comment: I think Name stays the same and that *John Doe* changes.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a optional newline char might help.  --> `\n?\r?`

**Ex:**

```
import re

body = """Name: John Doe"""

p = re.compile("Name:\s*\n?\r?(.*)")
result = p.search(body)
if result:
    s = result.group(1)
    print(s)
```

Comment: `\s*` only should work, `\s` is any white character, that includes newlines. ;) So `r"Name:\s*(.*)"` (use r, otherwise Python won't pass a raw string to re.compile and you might need multiple escapes then)