# Multiline String Python Regex

Tags: python, regex, multilinestring

I am trying to get the last number from this string from each line but my code is only able to get '25' instead. I want to get 15, 10, 5, 5, and 25.

```
import re

string = """

1073811-S0-A M3S FRT SUBFRAME MNT FRT INR LH 15
1073851-S0-A M3S REAR QUARTER INNER LH 10 
1080023-S0-C M3 ASY, COWL SIDE, LH 5 
1080024-S0-C M3 ASY, COWL SIDE, RH 5
1080473-S0-B M3 ASY, SHOTGUN TOWER, LH 25
"""

qty = re.findall(r'\d{1,3}$', string)

print(qty)
```

Comment: Use `qty = re.findall(r'(?m)(\d+)\s*$', string)`

Comment: You're looking for [`re.MULTILINE`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE)

Comment: Thank you Wiktor Stribiżew! Genius! Been working and Googling for hours!

Comment: @ForceBru - thank you as well. I will look more into this then. Previously i tried this but received errors so was thinking it was not it.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/587345/11301900.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the flag `re.MULTILINE`:

```py
qty = re.findall(r'\d{1,3}$', string, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

You get: `['15', '5', '25']`

But some line also ends with trailing white spaces.
So, you can use a group with a optional white space:

```py
qty = re.findall(r'(\d{1,3})\s*$', string, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

You get: `['15', '10', '5', '5', '25']`.

You can also search the numbers which are followed by an optional white space and the end a string. You can do that with a positive lookhead:

```py
qty = re.findall(r'\d{1,3}(?=\s*$)', string, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: @Dajuice911, you are welcome. You can accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
str="""1073811-S0-A M3S FRT SUBFRAME MNT FRT INR LH 15
1073851-S0-A M3S REAR QUARTER INNER LH 10 
1080023-S0-C M3 ASY, COWL SIDE, LH 5 
1080024-S0-C M3 ASY, COWL SIDE, RH 5
1080473-S0-B M3 ASY, SHOTGUN TOWER, LH 25"""
pattern = re.compile(r'(?m)(\d+)\s*$')
match = pattern.findall(str)
for i in match:
  print(i)
```

output is:
15
10
5
5
25