# How to fix xml tags containing whitespaces with python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I happen to receive xml files with broken tags that contain spaces or are split into two lines:

'<sometag>blablabla</som\n etag>'

I'd like to fix them with Python, so I've come up with the following:

```
import re
with open('file.xml', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()

broken_tags = re.findall('(<.*?\n[^(><.)]+>)', data)
fixed_tags = []

for tag in broken_tags:
    tag = tag.replace('\n', '').replace(' ', '')
    fixed_tags.append(tag)

iterator = 0
for tag in broken_tags:
    print(f'Tag {broken_tags[iterator]} will be replaced with {fixed_tags[iterator]}\n\n')
    re.sub(broken_tags[iterator], fixed_tags[iterator], data)
    iterator += 1
```

For starters re.sub does not replace the values even though it works if I provide strings instead of list items. And I have a feeling that there is some simpler, more pythonic way to achieve what I need. Can you help?

Comment: The regex needed is a multiline one, may be this can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/587620/2834978

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I dropped re.sub and used replace function instead and it seems to be working fine:

```
import re
with open('file.xml', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()

broken_tags = re.findall('(<.*?\n[^(><.)]+>)', data)
    
for tag in broken_tags:
    fixed_tag = tag.replace('\n', '').replace(' ', '')
    data = data.replace(tag, fixed_tag)
```

Yet I still have a feeling that it can be done much simper. Anyway, the above works fine.